# Wallpaper upload button missing - Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, system-settings, desktop-background

I try to install a wallpaper but miss the upload button. Of course I can google for "place for wallpaper ubuntu 18.04", but is that really what Ubuntu requires?
This is how an Ubuntu 18 looks like - did I miss something?
[image: sceenshot]

Answer (score 2):

The '**Pictures**' tab in the wallpaper selection window as in your screenshot gets populated by images in your `~/Pictures/` directory (or the '*Pictures*' folder in your home directory). So if you want a specific image to appear here, you simply need to copy/move the image to `~/Pictures/`.

Note that The *Pictures* tab shows images only from the 'Pictures' folder, **not even from any subfolder** of the Pictures folder.

If you're unhappy with the limited options this wallpaper selection window provides, you may use **(GNOME) Tweaks**. Install it by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Tweaks let you select image from any folder and also provides extra options to tile/zoom/centre/scale/fill/span the background image.

[image]

Comment: ok thanks that was easy! 

but honestly, why is the option to assign a wallpaper not included in basic Ubuntu 18.04?
The ~/Pictures/  folder and the others I always remove from the beginning, in this case it falls back to home folder.

Comment: @JoeSchraube If you find this answer useful you may consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.